# Git is showing added files but is not showing file differences

Tags: git, compare, push, branch, diff

I had a repository with a brach *master* and I created a branch with a name *dev* to copy branch *master*. Then I initialized a repository in a directory where there wasn't any repository. I did a force push to the *master* branch. The directory pushed to the repository contains the same files as the *dev* branch but with some differences.

At the moment when I'm comparing branches *master* and *dev*, Git is not showing differences between the same files but is showing modified files like they would not be present before so they are displayed as brand new files

I assume it is happening because I did a force push but I don't understand why. Is it possible to compare these two branches after force push? I do the comparison in GitLab.

Comment: Try `git diff branch_1...branch_2` and see what differences it is showing and if the differences are considerable then you can merge.

Comment: @AnkitJindal `git diff` is giving a different result than GitLab compare feature. The first method is giving a proper result. I am surprised that the result is different in GitLab.